# Script for a batch file that runs a program for a specific period of time

Tags: batch, script

I want a script for a batch file that makes a program run every 10 minutes for 5 seconds each time. In these 5 seconds, the program must be running on top of all the other windows, but out of focus so that it doesn't interrupt anything else that i might be doing at the time.

I need it for setting repetitive reminders, that i will write on a specific program.

Comment: SU isn't a script writing service.  Is there a specific problem with creating this that you are having trouble with?  Can you add what you've already tried to your question?

Comment: You want so much and do so little...

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a [scheduled task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) for this to run every 10 minutes. I'll leave the details of writing the script to you. If I was doing this I'd either use an API for the calendar I'm using from my own console style app or write to the data files directly. This is because scheduling GUI apps is error prone at best.